# Immediately invoked object literal

Tags: javascript, object, design-patterns, module

What does this snippet of code do? What is its practical usage? I didn't write this code. I found it here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7407896

```
!{
    //convenience methods here for create and expose via this
    create: function(options){
        //constructor logic here
        var created = Object.create(this.fn);
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
        this.plugins.forEach(function(plugin){
            plugin.apply(created, args);
        });
        return created;
    },
    fn:{//prototype methods here

    },
    expose:function(NameSpace, window, document, plugins){
        window[NameSpace] = this;//This can be tweaked for whatever
        this.document = document;
        this.plugins = plugins;
    }
}.expose("LibraryNamespace", window, document, []);
```

I am interested to know how is the above is any better than doing something like a revealing module pattern. Also I am unclear of the mechanism of the create function. Can someone walk me through the process of creating objects based on the prototypes passed in?

```
var libraryNameSpace= window.libraryNameSpace || {};
libraryNameSpace.myFeatureOne = (function(){
    var _bar = "_bar";
    var foo = "foo" + _bar;
    function foobar(){ return "foobar"; }
    return {
        myFoo : foo;
        fooBarMethod: foobar;
    };
})();
```

Comment: How would `create` be used?

Comment: That `expose` method is mixing up exposing and initialisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First code block starts with returning an object with three functions then invoke expose function which is constructor function that return an object according to it's arguments.
expose function will add this object to window object with its NameSpace.
It seem like this code might be useful when putting libraries to window object.

In second code block you are declaring a variable name libraryNameSpace to be window.libraryNameSpace or empty object. Since window.libraryNameSpace is probably undefined at this point. it will set the variable to object. Then you are adding a self invoking function on this object.

Major difference is how you are dealing with object. There are difference between {}, Object.create, new ConstructorFunc(), also mutability